# Pull a positioned grouped and repeating string using regex?

Tags: regex, perl, splunk

Lets say I have data output such as the following:

`0; root.; 0; MLG.; 247; root.; 249; MLG.; 2390; toasty.;` ... `someNumber; username.;`

I am trying to pull the username while ignoring the number and semicolon previous to it from when the numbers are not 0, and to do this for an unknown number of times. In regards to this data the output should appear favorably as:

`root. MLG. toasty.`

**The syntax MUST be perl format**. The application using this takes no exceptions. While I do have complete control over how this data is being presented (such as I can remove the semicolons next to the numbers and attach the unique number to the username with a period and separate with a semicolon)  I would like to know the method to do this regardless.

Some of the many current regexs I've tried is as follows...

*(The `(?<field>` is to specify the regex following the end `>` a field name to be specified and shown by the application in  case anyone is wondering)*

- Pulls all data to the last semicolon starting from where the first number shown is not 0.

`"(?<users_online>[1-9].*;)"`

- Pulls all data after the first instance of non-zero number and a semicolon occurs.

`"[1-9];(?<users_online>.*?)"`

- Pulls all data after the first instance of a non-zero number and a semicolon and outputs any alphanumeric values up until the next "word" boundry.

`"[1-9];((?<users_online> \w+\b))"`

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it more simple to extract usernames that follow a zero and to join them?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte From how I am interpreting this, it is not allowed. The users that follow a zero are users that can not be displayed. I am only concerned with the ones that follow a non-zero number

Comment: It isn't very different.

Comment: Your requirement is very hard to understand. What does this mean -- "_The (?<field> is to specify the regex following the end > a field name to be specified_" ?  You say, "_in case anyone is wondering_" -- this is the only time you mention that `(?<field>)` thing. What does `<users_online>` mean?  I see that you took pains to describe your problem, thank you for that, but I don't get it -- I don't see why the posted answer fails, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
my $s = "0; root.; 0; MLG.; 247; root.; 249; MLG.; 2390; toasty.; ... someNumber; username.;";
#                                          ^--- added
print join " ", $s=~/[1-9]0*; ([^;]+)/g;
```

You only need to describe at least one digit that isn't a zero before eventual zeros and to use an appropriate character class that excludes the semicolon.

Comment: I will try the syntax `/[1-9]0*; ([^;]+)/g;`. I do have doubts as the last time me and another person tried this, the application failed as it couldn't identify what `1` meant

Comment: Unfortunately this is incorrect. I should have mentioned that `(?<field>)` is required to be specified. I have tried altering the regex to be before and after the group name however that provides no information at all.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, it's a bit obscure, but I posted a working code you can test here: https://eval.in/598580

Comment: I cant make the question too specific as Stack Overflow users will brush over things that are not in their expertise. I can try to make the post a little more clarified but I feel we can build off of this. 

`(?<field>`regexstring`)` needs to be specified for the regex that matches the data. Your code works, but it lacks this portion of information.

Comment: @Jouster500  (1) So what is that `(?<field>)`? Is that some regex I've never seen?  (2) Also -- no users after `0`, right?  But in your example in your question you _do show_ those users in the output you favor.  (3) In the question you say Perl strictly (whatever that means), but now you say "_application failed as it couldn't identify what 1 meant_".  I don't understand.  `[1-9]` is as plain as it gets. What can one do if not that? Again, I see that you tried to explain but I don't quite understand.

Comment: @zdim: (2) it's because users that follow a 0 and users that dont' follow a 0 have the same names in the example!

Comment: The question is kind of moot now however. I was able to reorganize the data so it befits the things I need. Let me tell you, there are some pretty sloppy regexs in here but it gets the job done. As for the application, its using splunk regexs.  [link](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.4.1/SearchReference/Rex)